# How do I bind and show pre selected value instead of select in ss-multiselect-dropdown?

Tags: angular

I am using angular-2-dropdown-multiselect.

I am getting a list of values from back-end. I just want to bind them with ss-multiselect-dropdown and show them as auto selected in the dropdown.

This is my HTML

```
<ss-multiselect-dropdown
  name="multiselect"
  [texts]="myTexts"
  [settings]="mySettings"
  [options]="myOptions"
  [(ngModel)]="myOptions"
  formControlName="agent"
>
</ss-multiselect-dropdown>
```

These are in .ts files

```
myOptions: IMultiSelectOption[] = [];

mySettings: IMultiSelectSettings = {
  enableSearch: true,
  checkedStyle: 'fontawesome',
  buttonClasses: 'btn btn-primary btn-block',
  dynamicTitleMaxItems: 3,
  displayAllSelectedText: true
};

myTexts: IMultiSelectTexts = {
  checkAll: 'Select all',
  uncheckAll: 'Unselect all',
  checked: 'item selected',
  checkedPlural: 'items selected',
  searchPlaceholder: 'Find',
  searchEmptyResult: 'Nothing found...',
  searchNoRenderText: 'Type in search box to see results...',
  defaultTitle: 'Select',
  allSelected: 'All selected'
};
```

Comment: Hi karan, can reproduce issue on stackblitz?

Comment: can you explain, what exactly is not working? What error message do you receive? What did you already try?

Comment: Value is properly getting bind to the drop-down. But I have to click on the drop-down field and then I can see the binded value in the drop-down list. What I want is that it should be preselected and shown in the drop-down field instead of the drop-down list. Just like we bind a value in a text field.